# SASM debug x86 assembler code on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, 32-bit, sasm

I'm trying to debug a x86 assembler code in SASM on Ubuntu. I haven't got this to work. When I switch SASM to x64 mode, it works just fine. Is there any workaround to make the debugger also work in x64 mode?

Comment: Do you get any error message?  Are you programming on WSL, the Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Comment: Using native Linux Ubuntu 18.04. I don’t get an error message. SASM just gets stuck when I click debug (in x86 mode). It doesn’t allow me to step, go for breakpoints or anything else. Running without debug is fine and x64 mode is also fine.